# Use DLL without creating dependency, perhaps with Source Generator?

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I have this [library with utility methods](https://github.com/mysteryx93/HanumanInstitute.Validators) that are very useful all the time.

One thing that can be a little bit annoying, particularly when developing 3rd party NuGet libraries, is the extra dependency that it creates. Which makes me hesitate to use these shortcut methods on small public projects.

I was wondering, is there a way for `HanumanInstitute.Validators` to inject its method into the calling assembly and remove the need for external dependency? Perhaps using Source Generator? I guess one way would be to copy all the files into strings to code-gen; and have 2 versions of the NuGet package, a regular one, and a Source Gen version. The Source Gen version could be difficult to maintain though.

Is there any simpler way that this can be achieved?